# django curl localhost xml request

Tags: xml, django, curl

How can I curl xml to a django app running locally?

I can hit my endpoint with the following:

```
curl http://localhost:8000/api/remote/docusign_connect/ -H 'Accept: application/xml' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml'
```

However I'm unable to add any xml to the body of the request. I receive a `CSRF token missing or incorrect` error.

```
curl http://localhost:8000/api/remote/docusign_connect/ -b csrftoken=mycsrf -d "<status>A note</status>" -H 'Accept: application/xml' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml'
```

I also tried using `--data-urlencode` instead of just `-d`

How come I can hit the endpoint with the first curl request but not with the second? (csrf needed for second request but not the first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come I can hit the endpoint with the first curl request but not with the second? (csrf needed for second request but not the first)

In the first, you are doing `GET` request. `GET` request is considered safe against [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

In the second, you are doing `POST` request. `POST` request has a side effect on your system, thus there must be some kind of protection against [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

To solve this you need to provide the correct `csrftoken` in your second request. Usually you should be able to get the CSRF token by making `GET` request, since you have made your first `GET` request, the `csrftoken` should probably be passed alone in the HTTP Header or Cookie. (use the curl to print the header)

Here's the documentation about [Django CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#module-django.middleware.csrf)